# On the nilpotence of the matrix $AB-BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Given $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$ satisfy:

$rank(AB-BA)=1$

Prove that $(AB-BA)^{2}=0$

Generalize the problem if possible.

Any solution not mention Jordan canonical form would be appreciated!

Comment: Here is one way to generalise the problem statement: if $X$ is a rank-1 traceless matrix, $X^2=0$. The reason is simple: if $X=uv^T$, then $X^2=u(v^Tu)v^T=(v^Tu)uv^T=\operatorname{tr}(X)X$. Note that we don't need any field extension/completion (and hence any Jordan form) here. In fact, the argument works over any commutative ring (with the rank of a matrix $X$ defined as the minimum number $k$ such that $X$ can be written as a sum of $k$ nonzero outer products of the form $uv^T$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** show that $\text{tr}(AB - BA) = 0$.  Use this fact and the rank to find the Jordan Canonical form of $AB-BA$.

The generalization they want might be "what if $\text{rank}(AB-BA) = r$"?

---

Suppose that $AB - BA = UTU^*$ with $T$ upper triangular.  It follows that $T$ has a rank of $1$ and a trace of $0$.

Since $T$ has rank $1$, it has at most one non-zero diagonal entry.  However, if $T$ has a single non-zero entry on the diagonal, then it would have a non-zero trace.

So, $T$ is a strictly upper triangular matrix with rank $1$. In particular, $T$ has the form
$$
T = 
\pmatrix{
0&*&*\\
&\ddots&*\\
&&0
}
$$
Note that the rank of $T^2$ must be strictly less than the rank of $T$. It follows that $T^2$ has rank $0$, so that it must be the zero matrix.

Comment: I have already known that, then how?

Comment: Well then, what have you thought of so far?  You should have indicated what you've figured out when asking the question.  Anyway, how does the trace of a matrix relate to the eigenvalues of that matrix?

Comment: Why can't $AB - BA$ have any non-zero eigenspace?

Comment: Trace may be the sum of the eigenvalue?
I have tried using Schur decomposition then I prove that all diagonal elements of the upper triangular matrix are zero. Then I stuck, not moving anymore. I think it's not the solution direction so I don't mention it, giving people innocent idea :D

Comment: @Mr.T Schur decomposition can also work!  Assume that there is a non-zero entry on the diagonal.  Because $(AB - BA)$ is rank $1$, all other entries must be zero.

Comment: not really understand.
Jordan canonical form is over my knowledge.
I can prove $AB-BA$ is nilpotent, but I can't show the nil-degree is 2

Comment: @Mr.T if you know that $AB - BA$ is similar to a triangular matrix with $0$s on the diagonal and a rank of $1$, then it follows that $(AB - BA)^2 = 0$

Comment: How? I don't see it apparently

Comment: I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: @Mr.T In retrospect, I see you had most of what you needed.  The key insight was that if $T$ is nilpotent, then the rank of $T^2$ has to be (strictly) less than the rank of $T$.

Comment: Schur decomposition is overkill. One needs only know that a complex matrix is trigonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_j, j=1,\cdots,n$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The rank of $M$ is $1$. Hence there exists $a_j\in \mathbb{R}$, not all zero, and a vector $v=(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$, not zero, such that $Me_j=a_jv$ for all $j=1,\cdots,n$. We immediately have that the trace of $M$ is $T=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_n v_n$. Hence $T=0$.

Now, for $j=1,\cdots,n$:

$$M^2e_j=a_jMv= a_jM(\sum v_k e_k)=a_j(\sum v_k a_k v)=a_jTv=0$$
Hence $M^2=0$.